# Open Graph: How can I specify a property for time taken

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can specify a property when I need to showcase the time taken to complete the Action on the object.
e.g

```
1 hour 2 minutes
20 minutes 
2 minutes 20 seconds etc.
```

Facebook exposes a [DateTime](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/simpletypes/) Type. But the way I understand it’s the actual time and not a interval.

How can I specify something I like 320 seconds and OG will shows it in the appropriate division?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `duration` text template to display a custom property of your action-type.

Here's an example that displays a duration in an Open Graph Aggregation unit:

[image]

I have an action-type `sleep` at an object-type `bar`, and my Aggregation displays the duration of the naps.

Create action-type `sleep`, connect it to object-type `bar`, and create a custom property `sleep_seconds` that is an Integer:

[image]

The custom property `sleep_seconds` will hold the duration of the nap in seconds.

Next, create an OG Aggregation that will display the duration (called the `duration` Text Template):

[image]

My object-type `bar` has a custom property called `rating`, which is not important to `duration` but I show it just for fun -- it holds the rating of how good this bar is for sleeping :)

Finally, to publish an action I use the js-sdk and include the duration, `sleep_seconds`:

```
function post() {
  FB.api(
    '/me/esmithy_one:sleep',
    'post',
    {bar: 'http://www.plooza.com/og/bar11.html',
     sleep_seconds: 60*60*1 + 60*39 + 2  // h m s
    },
    function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Error occured');
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

If you really want to display "1 hour, 39 minutes, 2 seconds" instead of 1:39:02, then you could compute this in your code, convert it to a string, and save the string as a custom property of the action-type.  Your action-type's custom property would be `string` instead of `integer`, of course.

You can try this awesome app at:
http://plooza.com/og/sleep1.html

If you can't get your Aggregation unit to display in the user's Timeline, then try deleting **all other** aggregations except for the one you want to display. I had to do this when testing my test app. Also, publish enough actions to populate the aggregation unit.

More info:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/template/